# How can I use tag dispatch in MSVC without paying for it?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-explorer, empty-class, tag-dispatching

I am trying to use tag dispatch in C++ to enforce safety at runtime, but discovered via Compiler Explorer that MSVC fumbles this otherwise zero-cost abstraction by representing empty class tag types with a single byte: https://godbolt.org/z/Y7GxrPvaz.

```
class GuardType;

class TagType {
    friend GuardType;
    explicit TagType() = default;
};

// Imagine constructing this guard enforces a certain program state.
struct GuardType {
    explicit GuardType() = default;
    TagType GetTag() const { return TagType{}; }
};

void Example(TagType, TagType, TagType, TagType);

void Test() {
    const GuardType guard;
    const TagType tag = guard.GetTag();
    Example(tag, tag, tag, tag);
    Example(tag, tag, tag, tag);
}
```

GCC and Clang optimize away the empty class tag type entirely. In order for tag dispatch to be a suitable replacement for the code pattern it is replacing in my project, it must have no overhead whatsoever. I have read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/microsoft-specific-modifiers and found nothing that could help me. I understand this failing is probably for ABI compatibility of passing existing empty classes by value, but is there any way to make new empty classes optimize well on MSVC?

Comment: could you use templates rather than parameters? https://godbolt.org/z/Ka8cv8nbT

Comment: @AlanBirtles Templates are not an option. In my application, TagType has a private constructor, and can only be constructed by a helper function which enforces certain guarantees about the program's state. In other words, the goal is to create functions with TagType as a parameter which are only invokable when certain criteria at runtime are met.

Comment: you should [edit] this requirement into your question, a [mre] of a complete program using this would also be useful

Comment: All objects in C++ must have a size and a unique address (relative to other objects of the same type).   No unique address is a new feature that relaxes the 2nd.  Eliding the entire function call can eliminate variables, but ABIs cannot allow a non-elided call to not give tags their own address.  Tuples of tags with distinct types can all share the same address, and some std tuples support that.

Comment: There can't be object of size zero, so it is possible to iterate over none empty array of this object where begin and end points to different locations.

Comment: The passing of multiple TagType parameters to the Example function was to make it visually clear on Compiler Explorer that each parameter was being allocated on MSVC, and would not on GCC and Clang. In my application, only one TagType parameter is needed. I am aware of the C++ language rule that there are no zero byte objects, but I believe I am asking about compiler optimizations, not standard rules. And ABIs clearly can allow this optimization in value semantics, because I cannot get GCC or Clang to emit code for allocating empty class tag type parameters even with optimizations disabled.